# Mutex on 1 byte shared resource

Tags: synchronization, cpu-architecture

Is Mutex required on 1 byte shared resource? If not then why not? Consider I am using normal desktop PC pentium IV , 32 bit. Will condition change if use core 2 duo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you are going to do with it, but if you have multiple writers, implemented in C or C++, then yes you need a mutex - the size of the resource is not the issue.

Comment: Just to clear my doubts: If CPU is Single processor then while reading single byte (or word on 32 bit machine) if interrupt happens will it context switch after reading/writing a complete word or conext switch happen immediately? In short how many CPU cycles are required for reading/writing complete word.

Comment: @alam It doesn't matter how many clock cycles it takes - to update  a value, the compiler can emit code that basically does a read, a change and a write (i.e. at least three machine instructions) , and without a mutex a switch to another thread can take place after any of them..

Answer (score 0):

CPU doesn't matter as the task scheduler is free to interrupt a thread at any time.  Size doesn't matter.  If it's shared then you need some method of locking.